# How to create an hyperlink in a paragraph using php

Tags: php

I would like to create hyperlinks to the words in a paragraph.

For instance if the `"Jim Carrey"` name is in the array matches the word in string, then the Jim Carrey name should be in Hyperlink of `"www.domian.net/name(Jim Carrey)"` .
 If the `"mask"` word in the array matches the word in string then it should be replace with corresponding url like `"www.domian.net/mask"`

```
<?php 

$string="Jim Carrey found the new Mask";

$array=array("Jim Carrey","mask");

echo preg_replace( '/\b('.implode( '|', $array ).')\b/i', '<a href=" ">$1</a>', $string  );

?>
```

Comment: Good looks like your code works, what do you want?

Comment: Why would you want an address with brackets in it???? It would be much better to `www.domain.net/name/jimCarrey` or `www.domain.net/name/Jim_Carrey` etc

Comment: i am searching for , If Jim Carrey in the array = Jim Carrey in the string then ,the Jim Carrey in the string should be replaced with url  .

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have the right idea about how to put a link around the chosen text, but you seem to have not even tried to put in an `href`. Which is a shame, since it's as simple as typing in the URL with whatever parameter you want.

However, it does get a little complicated because you don't want the same thing both times (you want the literal word in one, but you want `name(WORD)` in the other). You could try this:

```
$array = array("Jim Carrey"=>"name(Jim Carrey)","mask"=>"mask");
echo preg_replace_callback("/\b".implode("|",array_keys($array))."\b/i",
   function($m) use ($array) {
       return "<a href=\"http://domain.net/".$array[$m]."\">".$m."</a>";
   },$string);
```

Comment: How to implement this concept to user defined url ?

Comment: +1 Just to show some appreciation for your answer as no one else seems to have done!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$string="Jim Carrey found the new Mask";

$arr=array("Jim Carrey","Mask");

foreach($arr as $val)
    $string = str_replace($val, '<a href="http://domain.com/' . $val . '">' . $val . '</a>', $string);

echo $string;
?>
```

Comment: How to assign an User defined url instead of variables? By using variable as links there are lot of error generated pages

Comment: @ADHI so you have predefined URLs for `Jim Carrey` and `Mask`? if yes, where it's stored?